# BaseX DBA Gui performance

Tags: basex

Running queries via REST BaseX api is just instantaneous compared to running it via Queries screen in DBA console which uses RESTXQ. Has anyone faced this issue? or please could you share your experience resolving it. Second question was do we need to open a particular DB before running a query or is there an option to allow Database be left open at all times.